# Ubuntu 18.04 suddenly freezes alot and becomes very laggy

Tags: 18.04

A few days ago my computer became very laggy, programs would frequently freeze for several minutes, then crash. The Cpu never seems that tasked however, it is always low on usage. Any ideas?

Comment: There's a known bug in gnome-shell in Ubuntu 18.04 and 17.10 - please see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1672297  If your system's memory consumption is increasing significantly, that's likely the cause. No solution yet with GNOME, but the problem does not occur with xfce and kde.

Comment: I don't think that is it, ram usage isn't high when this happens

Comment: Have you tried updating your system? I had a similar issue when I initially installed 18.04 but it sort of disappeared after two days or so.